# How to import moment.js in es6 file using having babel-loader.?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, momentjs, es6-modules

I am using vuejs framework and inside this we have created commonjs module to keep all the common code together.

This involves moment library as well. I tried importing it in below ways:

```
import moment from 'moment';
moment();

import * as moment from 'moment';

import moment from '../node_modules/moment/moment';
```

But it's giving error after building that

```
Moment is not defined..
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw below you mentioned that you want to avoid using any other packages, but I would urge you to consider using day.js instead of moment.js if you don't require any of moment's more advanced features. It will save you a massave headache and take a ton off your bundle size. You also won't need to figure out how to shim it in. It's just a simple `import` statement.

Comment: @selfagency Thanks for your suggestion. But i cannot change the library at the last moment. because we have already pushed our code to production only thing which we are doing now is moving duplicate code to common module. 
And this common module having dependency for 'moment' library. The last option is to use moment-es6 wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [moment-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-es6) wrapper?

Comment: Thanks for the response..I checked that package but not yet tried it. I am just trying to avoid any other packages.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like this?
I always use it like this then in vue.js

Package I Use

```
"moment": "^2.21.0",

/** * Moment * **/
    window.moment = require('moment');
```

And vue pages

```
 data(){
        return {
            page_data: '',
            moment: window.moment,
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .. but seems like you are using global window object.. are you sure about using global window object for storing moment instance ?